# How can I add 3 List into one ListView by splitting columns

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

I am creating a Log Analyzer for specific debug logs. A log is set up like this

```
[16Oct2019 09:03:16.150] [main/DEBUG] [net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLLoader/CORE]: FML 28.1 loading
```

Now I created 4 Lists, each one containing one part of the log.

```
List1 contains [16Oct2019 09:03:16.150]
List2 contains [main/DEBUG]
List3 contains [net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLLoader/CORE]: FML 28.1 loading
```

and LogList containing the entire Log, only splitted by line:

```
LogList[0] = "[16Oct2019 09:03:16.150] [main/DEBUG] [net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLLoader/CORE]: FML 28.1 loading"
LogList[1] = "[16Oct2019 09:03:16.150] [main/DEBUG] [net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLLoader/CORE]: FML found ModLauncher version : 4.0.0+61+ca3b447"
etc.
```

In my UserControl I have a ListView:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding LogList}"/>
```

But I don't want the ListView containing this LogList. I want the ListView being split in 3 parts. One containing List1 with the DateTimes, the second containing List2 with the Debug Type, and the last one containing List3 with the Debug Text, so I can easily disable unimportant logs, and focus on the errors, or just hide the date so it's easier to read

Comment: You can add the `GridViewColumn` in `ListView` to define multiple columns. You can follow the reference at [here](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-with-gridview/)

Comment: Create an object that will hold 3 properties and store it in a list, then bind those properties to your list view. You don't even have to implement INPC, as this is just going to be a read only list. But please use observable colleciton. Those 4 lists really surprised me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this class:

```
class EventLogItem
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Event { get; set; }
    public string FullLine => $"{Date} {Category} {Event}";
}
```

And XAML for your ListView:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding LogList}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,0,0,0" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Date/Time" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Date}" Width="150" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Category" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Category}" Width="150" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Event" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Event}" Width="300" />
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```